$∆ABC$ and point $D$ on $BC$. $O_1$,$O_2$,$O_3$ are the circumcenters of triangles $∆ABC$, $∆ACD$, and $∆ABD$. Prove that $AO_3O_1O_2$ is cyclic.
Consider $\triangle ABC$ and point $D$ on $BC$. $O_1, O_2, O_3$ are the circumcenters of $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle ACD$, $\triangle ABD $. Prove that $AO_3O_1O_2$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

I also asked my teacher, and he gave me a hint. The hint is that you can prove the equality of $\alpha$ in this picture:

These two are my proof of the hint and my draft but i still couldn't prove the main question.
Of course, there are other ways to prove this question besides this hint.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Consider the figure in your "proof of the hint" picture. Observe that $O_1O_2$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ and $O_1O_3$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ (since the perpendicular bisector $AC$ passes through $O_1$ and $O_2$, similarly for $AB$). Suppose that $O_1O_3$ intersects $AB$ at $E$ and $O_1O_2$ intersects $AC$ at $F$. It is clear that $AEO_1F$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and hence  $\angle EAF + \angle EO_1F = 180^\circ$ or $\angle BAC + \angle O_3O_1O_2 = 180^\circ.$
Now deduce that $\angle O_3AO_2 + \angle O_3O_1O_2 = 180^\circ$ using $\angle O_3AB = \angle O_2AC$ (simple angle chasing should work).

You already have a nice diagram as follows. However, how are you sure if you extend $BO_3$ and $CO_2$, they intersect on the circle at $A'$? That's exactly the same as the claim of the hint, which you are supposed to prove!
Instead, you can simply use the fact that:
$$\angle AO_3B=\angle AO_2C=2\angle ADB,$$
which implies $\angle BAO_3=\angle O_2AC= \alpha. $
Now, note that $O_1O_3$ and $O_1O_2$ are respectively perpendicular to $AB$ and $AC$. Therefore:
$$\angle AO_3O_1=90^{\circ}+\alpha, \\ \angle AO_2O_1=90^{\circ}-\alpha,$$
which proves the claim.


Thanks, i fixed it.
